# Create a matrix by sliding down a given vector by one step for every column

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization

Given this vector

```
a = [1 2 3 4]
```

I want to create a matrix like this

```
b = [1 0 0 0;
     2 1 0 0;
     3 2 1 0;
     4 3 2 1;
     0 4 3 2;
     0 0 4 3;
     0 0 0 4]
```

in a vectorized way not using loops.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to do it:

```
a = [1 2 3 4]
n = numel(a);

%// create circulant matrix from input vector
b = gallery('circul',[a zeros(1,n-1)]).' %'

%// crop the result
c = b(:,1:n)
```

---

Another way:

```
b = union( tril(toeplitz(a)), triu(toeplitz(fliplr(a))),'rows','stable')
```

or its slightly variation

```
b = union( toeplitz(a,a.*0),toeplitz(fliplr(a),a.*0).','rows','stable')
```

and probably even faster:

```
b = [ toeplitz(a,a.*0) ; toeplitz(fliplr(a),a.*0).' ]
b(numel(a),:) = []
```

Comment: I keep forgetting about `gallery`! +1

Answer (score 7):

Hint: use [`conv2`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv2.html) (hover mouse to see code):

> `a = [1 2 3 4];` 
> `b = conv2(a(:), eye(numel(a)));`

Or, in a similar mood, you can use [`convmtx`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/convmtx.html) (from the Signal Processing Toolbox):

> `a = [1 2 3 4];` 
> `b = convmtx(a(:), numel(a));`

Comment: I first need to convolute my brain to get that :p +1

Comment: @thewaywewalk Hahaha. My brain has been already spoilt by years of exposure to signal theory :-)

Answer (score 2):

With `bsxfun` -

```
na = numel(a)
b = zeros(2*na-1,na)
b(bsxfun(@plus,[1:na]',[0:na-1]*2*na)) = repmat(a(:),1,na)
```

If you are looking for a [faster pre-allocation](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/preallocation-performance), you can do -

`b(2*na-1,na) = 0;`.

Answer (score 2):

Another `bsxfun` -

```
a=[1 2 3 4];
m=numel(a);
b=[a,zeros(1,m-1)].';

Q=bsxfun(@circshift, b, [0:m-1])
```

Comment: @Divakar - My first `bsxfun` answer!